# Prettier replacing comma to semicolon

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm declaring a class in typescript with an object type.

```
metadataList: {
  name: string[],
  metadata: Object;
};
```

My actual problem is that prettier is replacing comma with semicolon when I save.
so it gives me

```
metadataList: {
  name: string[];
  metadata: Object;
};
```

And this is causing me error when I set `metadataList.name` : `proprety undefined`.

How can I disable this feature ?

Comment: That is not the root cause of your issue.

Comment: As mentioned above - not related to prettier, `metadataList` is likely undefined